# Should I change a question to reflect the answer?

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

Referring to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80555/how-to-un-optimize-my-computer-to-run-older-games-specifically-portal-vs-por), but applies probably to other questions.

Sometime a user has a question, usually a tech issue, which he asks for a specific solution. A suggested answer might suggest a solution for the problem but not the one specifically asked for (for example, user didn't identify the problem correctly). If the user accepts this answer, we are left with a "solved" question which the accepted answer looks unrelated to, leaving the title of the question a bit misleading.

When cases like this occur, should the original question be altered to better reflect the accepted answer?

For example, is it appropriate to change [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80555/how-to-un-optimize-my-computer-to-run-older-games-specifically-portal-vs-por) from "How to “un-optimize” my computer to run older games?" to "How can I reduce screen tearing when running games on a fast machine?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When concerned with issues such as this, you can determine the best course of action by considering what another person in your situation would type into Google when looking for an answer to their problem.

In your particular case, changing the question title would be beneficial to future visitors. You should leave the content of the question the same, however, to provide context for the answers and comments. This also helps people find your question depending on what they search for.